# Panic error while reading file lua

Tags: c, lua, lua-api

I created a file with the following code

```
Request = {
  TimeAdd = true;
  DaysAdd = true;
};
```

The source code is made in C

```
    lua_getglobal(L, "Request")
    lua_getfield(L, -1, "TimeAdd");

       time_request = lua_toboolean(L, -1);

    lua_getfield(L, -1, "DaysAdd");
        data_request = lua_toboolean(L, -1);
```

I do the compilation of the program normally more it occurs error lua

LUA PANIC: unprotected error in call to Lua API (attempt to index boolean value)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: What didn't you understand? Before the old code reading was fine, but now after the change occurs panic error. Error debugging `lua_getfield(L, -1, "TimeAdd");`

Comment: At least you should show the courtesy to read my comment carefully.

Comment: Edited the topic explaining better, understand now?

Comment: Try `lua_getfield(L, -2, "DaysAdd");`

Comment: Thank you Egor, is working now.

Answer (score 2):

Step through the code, visualizing the Lua stack as you go, and the error will become apparent.

```
lua_getglobal(L, "Request"); // Stack: [] -> [(Request table)]
lua_getfield(L, -1, "TimeAdd"); // [>(Request table)<] -> [(Request table), true]

time_request = lua_toboolean(L, -1); // [(Request table), >true<]

lua_getfield(L, -1, "DaysAdd"); // [(Request table), >true<] ERROR: Cannot index `true`
```

When you call `lua_getfield(L, -1, "DaysAdd")`, the top of the stack is the value `true`, which is not indexable.

Either pop the `true` value off the stack before getting DaysAdd (`lua_pop(L, 1)`) or adjust the stack index to `lua_getfield` to point to the Request table (`lua_getfield(L, -2, "DaysAdd")`)

Comment: Thank you Colonel, it's working now. I'm new in lua, have some indication of some stuff for me to read more about respect?

Comment: @Chozie If you haven't, try reading the Lua book. (The old version is available online at http://www.lua.org/pil/contents.html – slightly outdated by now, but still mostly relevant.) Also useful is reading the source of Lua libraries written in C, see e.g. the section "Libraries" of the [Lua source](http://www.lua.org/source/5.3/) for Lua's built-in libraries, or whatever other libraries you use or find via luarocks. (Not everything you'll find will be good code, but if you look at many different things you'll probably see some good code, too.)